# How to change resolution for mirror display ( ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: 14.04, display-resolution

I don't have a graphics card. My monitors resolution is 1333*768 . But mirror display only suppourts 1024*768 . It it possible to change that to 1333*768 ?

Comment: running `xrandr` on command line it will show you which resolutions are supported for every connected monitor/display, and only those. It's a hardware thing, not software.

Comment: Thanks, if I add a GPU will I be able to use higher resolution ? @bistoco

Comment: If by GPU, you mean a graphics card, yes, but i really dont know if you can use both at the same time, so i will go for a dedicated graphics card with at least 2 outputs.